# read a specific word from string and parse the second line from it

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a program in java where i am getting from html data from css class `.report`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/medindiaparser",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelMap  medindiaparser(@RequestParam  String  urlofpage ) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException  {
    System.out.println("saveMedicineName");
    ModelMap mv = new ModelMap(urlofpage);
    System.out.println();
     String url = urlofpage;
     Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        String TITLE = document.select(".report").text();
        String[] news = TITLE.split(":");
        System.out.println("Question: " + TITLE);


    return mv;
}
```

Now what `TITLE` is giving me.

```
name : aman kumar working in : home,outside what he does: program | sleep | eat
```

So what i want to get the specific value in an array like.

```
array[0] : aman kumar
array[1] : home,outside
array[2] : program | sleep | eat
```

So that, i can set the value of array in my models, anyone did it?

`.report` consist `<h3>` where header is located. it goes like this

```
<report><h3>Name</h3>aman kumar<h3>working in </h3>home, outside .....</report>
```

Comment: Are your field name's always the same and given in the same order ? ('name', 'working in','what he does')
If yes you can substring these part

Comment: Are you sure that to call `text()` on `select(".report")`? Maybe this selection holds data in structure which would allow you to split it in separate parts easier than with `split` method.

Comment: as i said what title is giving me 'name : aman kumar working in : home,outside what he does: program | sleep | eat' and this is all i can select because data is wrapped in .report class

Comment: I understand what TITLE holds, but that is not what I am asking. You are getting text representation of what `select(".report")` was able to find. But maybe this select was able to find data in form `<span>name : aman kumar</span> <span>working in : home,outside</span> <span>what he does: program | sleep | eat</span>` (or similar) which provides data in specific groups. Handling such groups one by one would be easier then having to guess which part belongs to which group, so if we should split `aman kumar working in` before `working` or `kumar` or maybe before `in`.

Comment: no no acttually .report consist <h3> where header is located . it goes like this <report><h3>Name</h3>aman kumar<h3>working in </h3>home, outside .....</report> @Pshemo

Comment: So there is structure which allows us to parse it properly. Post this structure in your question and we can try help you using parser to solve this problem. Currently you are facing problem described at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Comment: But be sure to post proper data. For now you claim that it looks like `<report>..</report>` but if that would be true `select(".report")` wouldn't be able to find it because `.report` selects classes, not tag names.

Comment: @Pshemo check your answer's comment section

Answer (score 1):

I have completely overhauled my answer to extract the `name`, `working in`, and `what he does` contents from your `TITLE` string.  This can be done using a regex pattern matcher in Java.

```
String pattern = "name\\s*:\\s*(.*?)\\s*working in\\s*:\\s*(.*?)\\s*what he does\\s*:\\s*(.*)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
String line = "name : aman kumar working in : home,outside what he does: program | sleep | eat";
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
    System.out.println(m.group(3));
}
```

**Output:**

```
aman kumar
home,outside
program | sleep | eat
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: it is not workin in my case remember aman
home
program is variable

Comment: Then you didn't ask a clear question.  Please update with your actual question.

Comment: update the question actaully the string is mixed with all type of , | =

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String s = "name : aman kumar working in : home,outside what he does: program | sleep | eat";
String[] news = s.split(":");
String exclude = "(working in|what he does)";
int index = -1;
for(int i = 0 ; i < news.length ; i++){
    if("name".equals(news[i].trim())){
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
if(index != -1){
    String[] content = Arrays.copyOfRange(news, index+1, news.length);
    for(String string : content){
        System.out.println(string.trim().replaceAll(exclude, ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: not working .. actually it is giving the first value very fine aman then it goes wrong after this and giving me random

Comment: Updated the answer, try now?

Comment: It's actually in an array only. `content` is an array.

Comment: but it is in single array